# How do i insert all column values from a table into a second identical table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Lets assume i have these tables

```
FooTable                     BarTable
id    value                  id    value
```

`BarTable` is acting as a mirrored table for `FooTable` and shall at some points recieve copies of entire rows from `FooTable`

Now, as i've tried this:

```
Insert Into BarTable select * from FooTable where yadi yada
```

and it feels horrible to use the `*`.

Is there any other way i might approach this?

Comment: Why do you need two tables to hold the same data?

Comment: @AdamHaines Third time i'm editing this comment to make any sense. It's a table to hold backup-data.

Comment: Been there done that :).  Have you considered using a trigger to move the data you need into the backup table?  Or is the data that you need so random that it is easier to do this on demand manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Insert Into BarTable
(id, value)
select
id, values
from FooTable
where yadi yada
```

Comment: Thanks. On a sidenote, would this be good practice even if said tables have around 60 columns?

Answer (score 2):

Please see below, I create a temp table with data then insert all data into an identical tables, one with an identity column one without.

```
CREATE TABLE #TableOne ( field1 int, field2 int )
CREATE TABLE #TableTwo ( field1 int, field2 int )

INSERT INTO #TableOne ( Field1, Field2 ) VALUES ( 100, 200 )
INSERT INTO #TableOne ( Field1, Field2 ) VALUES ( 101, 201 )
INSERT INTO #TableOne ( Field1, Field2 ) VALUES ( 102, 201 )

INSERT INTO #TableTwo
SELECT * FROM #TableOne

-- If table that your loading data into has an Identity column you need to turn it off and you need 
-- to specificy each column
CREATE TABLE #TableThree ( field1 int IDENTITY(1,1), field2 int )
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TableThree ON 

INSERT INTO #TableThree ( Field1, Field2 )
SELECT * FROM #TableOne

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TableThree OFF
```

You can use this code if you have a large amount of fields in your table and don't want to manually script each out.

```
DECLARE @TableColumns AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @TableColumns = ISNULL(@TableColumns,'') + CASE WHEN @TableColumns IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ', ' END + '[' + C.Name + ']'
FROM SYS.Columns C
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable')

PRINT 'INSERT INTO NewTable ( ' + @TableColumns + ')'
PRINT 'SELECT ' + @TableColumns + ' FROM MyTable'
```